# Custom Eclipse RAP Dialog with JFace from Viewpart

Tags: java, dialog, jface

I have a class "View" which extends a ViewPart.
After sth in my class I want to show a dialog, which contains of two labels.

First I used "InputDialog" like this:

```
        Composite composite = new Composite(top, SWT.NONE);
    Label label= new Label(tmpComposite, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("");

    InputDialog dlg;
        dlg = new InputDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(),
                "Title", "Some Text", label.getText(), insertValidator());
    if (dlg.open() == Window.OK) {
        //Do sth.                   
    }
```

This works. But now I have two labels. How can I realize it? 
I found a few solutions, but none of them is working in a ViewPart or with Eclipse RCP.

Thanks for your help!

By the way if your solution is to call a java class from my "View", how can I come back to "View" and how can I see my new dialog? Tried it, not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom dialog by extending `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog 
{
  public MyDialog(Shell parentShell)
  {
    super(parentShell);
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) 
  {
    Composite container = (Composite)super.createDialogArea(parent);

    // Add your controls here

    return container;
  }
}
```

You use this in a similar way to `InputDialog`

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(shell);
dialog.open();
```

Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDialogs/article.html for some more details.